# Why doesn't find work recursively with a wildcard over SSH?

Tags: command-line, ssh, find

I'm connected to a CentOS server through SSH from macOS.  When I try to `find` with a wildcard at the beginning, it seems to only search the current directly, no recursion.  But if I put the wildcard at the end of the filename, it works.  I don't have this problem on the local Mac.

```
# find . -name *.inc
./copra_xml_gen.settings.inc
#
# find . -name auth.inc
./common_v4/auth.inc
./v5_old/common/auth.inc
./common/auth.inc
./v6/common/auth.inc
./v5/common/auth.inc
#
# find . -name auth*
./common_v4/auth.inc
./v5_old/common/auth.inc
./common/auth.inc
./v6/common/auth.inc
./v5/common/auth.inc
```

Comment: You realise, that by writing doesn't twice, you actually say does, right?

Comment: In the first example, it only finds one file, but I want it to find everything ending with `*.inc`

Comment: Note: SSH is completely irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is performing filename expansion **before** invoking `find`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions

You want to protect the pattern from the shell:

```
find . -name '*.inc'
```

or

```
find . -name \*.inc
```

In your current directory:

- you have a file that matches `*.inc` and the shell replaces that word with the actual filename in your find command.
- you do *not* have a file that matches `auth*`, so the pattern is *not* replaced.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. But what do you mean by "the shell puts replaces that"?

Comment: Sloppy writing. Edited.